# Cordova AngularJS app with Firebase - Writing to firebase ref fails after <textarea> has had focus

Tags: angularjs, firebase, cordova-3, angularfire

I have an AngularJS app which I'm running on Cordova (Android). It connects to a Firebase DB and pushes an object.

It works well in Chrome and it works in Cordova (Android). However, on Android, if I click on the textarea which brings up the keyboard the object is not longer pushed to Firebase.

- I have working code here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/efibo
- I tried both Angular 1.2.18 and 1.3.0-beta.13.
- I don't get any info watching adb logcat.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.13/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.17/firebase.js'></script>

  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Angular JS Demo</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
<h1>Comments</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
    <form novalidate>
        <textarea placeholder="Add comment" ng-model="comment.text"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="tiny button pull-right" ng-click="addTestComment(comment)">Add Comment</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var firebase_url = "https://<secret>.firebaseio.com";
function ctrl($scope){
  $scope.comment = {'text':'Placeholder comment'};
  $scope.addTestComment = function(comment) {
    var cmt = {'text':'Test Comment 1', 'created':new Date().getTime()};
    cmt.text = comment.text;
    var ref = new Firebase(firebase_url).child('comments-test');
    ref.push(cmt);
  };
}

</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to include cordova.js in my HTML. Including it solves the problem:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```